# Determining if a EnvDTE.Project is available

Tags: c#, .net, envdte

I'm having to go through a big solution that contains **unavailable projects**. These unavailable projects are unavailable because their paths don't exist anymore. If this solution were to keep these unavailable references, would there be a way to determine if each project I am looping on is available/unavailable?

Below is a loop whose goal is to determine if every ProjectItem within the current solution is saved. But, since certain projects are unavailable, I keep getting null references.

```
bool isDirty = false;
foreach (Project proj in sln.Projects) //sln is my current solution
{
    if (proj == null) //hoping that might do the trick
        continue;
    foreach (ProjectItem pi in proj.ProjectItems)
    {
        if (pi == null) //hoping that might do the trick
            continue;
        if (!pi.Saved)
        {
            isDirty = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite this in a simple `LINQ` operation:

```
//import the LINQ extensions
using System.Linq;
// some code here;
bool isDirty = sln.Projects.Any(pr => pr.ProjectItems != null && !pr.Saved);
```

According to the MSDN, the [`_Solution.Projects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte._solution.projects.aspx) property is a [`Projects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.projects.aspx) typed, which is a `IEnumerable` without generic, so you should use the [`OfType<TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx) extension method, like this:

```
bool isDirty = sln.Projects.OfType<Project>().Any(pr => pr.ProjectItems != null && !pr.Saved);
```

From MSDN:

> This method is one of the few standard query operator methods that can
>   be applied to a collection that has a non-parameterized type, such as
>   an `ArrayList`. This is because `OfType<TResult>` extends the type
>   `IEnumerable`. `OfType<TResult>` cannot only be applied to collections
>   that are based on the parameterized `IEnumerable<T>` type, but
>   collections that are based on the non-parameterized `IEnumerable` type
>   also.

Comment: What does the compiler say? May be you need a cast or `using` directive.

Comment: Make sure you have using System.Linq; on the top.

Comment: I do have the using. Could it be because my DTE object is EnvDTE80.DTE2 typed? Also, my "sol" is of the type EnvDTE. Not quite sure why it won't work...

Comment: What's the type of the `sln.Projects` property?

Comment: Here is what I had to do : sln.Projects.OfType<Project>().Any(pr => pr.ProjectItems != null && pr.Saved);